# Constructor Type Coercion in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, type-conversion

Take the following class:

```
     class mytype {
        double num;
     public:
        mytype(int a) {
           num = sqrt(a);
        }
        void print() {
           cout << num;
        }
     }
```

Say there is a method which takes a mytype:

```
 void foo(mytype a) {
    a.print();
 }
```

Is it legal c++ (or is there a way to implement this) to call foo(4), which would (in theory) output 2? From what I can glean you can overload type casts from a user defined class,  but not to. Can constructor do this in a standards-compliant manner (assuming, of course, the constructor is not explicit). Hopefully there is a way to in the end have this legal:

```
 int a;
 cin >> a;
 foo(a);
```

Note: this is quite obviously not the actual issue, but just an example for posting purposes. I can't just overload the function because of inheritance and other program-specific issues.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Actually, this is the **default** action if the declaration of your class is `#include`d.

To disallow this, your class constructor must be declared `explicit`. Note that only constructors that take one parameter (or constructors where every argument after the first has a default value) can use type coercion.

It is considered good practice to make all constructors `explicit` unless specifically desired. Note that even if your constructor **is** explicit, you can still do an anonymous conversion: `foo(mytype(4));`

Comment: Thank you. This behavior is desired, in this case. Does this also work if foo took the superclass of mytype? Also, why must it be 4.0?

Comment: I think rlbond didn't notice that the constructor mytype(int a) takes an int argument and the constructor internally converts it to double.

Comment: @Windows programmer: you're correct. However, apparently this conversion is valid anyway for built-ins (but not for classes).

Answer (score 1):

You can define conversions from native types as constructors like that, and conversions to native types such as `operator int()`.

The only restrictions are that you cannot redefine conversion *between* native types, or (re)define operators operating only on native types, or define certain operators at all outside their operand class.